# Finding Linear transformation, that transforms original point in addition to consecutive images .

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[Original Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ry36C.png)

I have inferred from the question that a linear transformation T, originally transforming point (1,3), also transforms its image(-2,-3) in adittion to the image following that(2,4). However when attempting to find the matrix trasnforming (1,3) to (-2,-3), i found it was inconsistant with that which transformed (-2,-3) to (2,4). So i am led to conclude thati have not understood the question correctly.
Attempted Working: T(X) = X' .  T=$\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{bmatrix}$

$\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{bmatrix}$·$\begin{bmatrix}1\\3\end{bmatrix}$ = $\begin{bmatrix}a +3b\\c+3d\end{bmatrix}$ $=>$ $a+3b = -2$ & $c+3d=-3$

$\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{bmatrix}$·$\begin{bmatrix}-2\\-3\end{bmatrix}$ = $\begin{bmatrix}-2a -3b\\-2c-3d\end{bmatrix}$ $=>$ $-2a-3b = 2$ & $-2c-3d=4$

$\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{bmatrix}$·$\begin{bmatrix}2\\4\end{bmatrix}$ = $\begin{bmatrix}2a +4b\\2c+4d\end{bmatrix}$ $=>$ $2a+4b = -3$ & $2c+4d=-11$

There shouldn't be any x or y values that satisfy all 3 or else an equation is redundant according to https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/three-equations-two-unknowns.426629/
, so i'm just wondering how i'm interpreting it wrong. The answer is  1/2$\begin{bmatrix}-1 & -1\\-21 & 5\end{bmatrix}$ according to my textbook.

Comment: Was it really less work to take and crop a picture, upload it and link it into your question than simply typing in the two sentences? You clearly understand how to use MathJax. In the future please include key parts of your question as actual text instead of images of text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re right. There is no such linear transformation: $(2,4)^T = \frac23(1,3)^T-\frac23(-2,-3)^T$, but $(-3,-11)^T \ne \frac23(-2,-3)-\frac23(2,4)$. The textbook answer doesn’t match the problem as stated, either, since it doesn’t map $(-2,-3)^T$ to $(2,4)^T$.

Looks like there’s a typo in the problem itself. If you change it to “... *and* the point $(2,4)$...” the given solution works and is easily computed as $$\begin{bmatrix}-2&-3\\-3&-11\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}1&2\\3&4\end{bmatrix}^{-1}.$$

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a typo in the text, it should be

$$\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}1\\3\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}-2\\-3\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}2\\4\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}-3\\-11\end{bmatrix}$$

which can be solved to obtain the answer.